# Background image displays locally but not on the web

Tags: css

I used the css transform property on an image so that it rotates (180 deg on hover) :

```
 .main-img:hover {
      transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
```

then I added a background image using an id so that when my main-image rotates on hover the background image is visible behind it:

```
#photo {     
  background-image: url("images/gauntlet2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[page locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zkH5.png)
When I run my index.html locally everything renders perfectly. I am able to see the background image when the main image rotates 180 deg; however, when I run the index.html from the web, instead of displaying the background image on hover it only displays the background color. I have deleted and re-transferred my files to my site but the discrepancy remains. Does anyone know why the same file on the same browser is being is rendering different locally and on the web.
[page on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggQSp.png)

Comment: Please edit the question and provide a link to the website.

Comment: Without seeing the actual page, we can't say anything definitive. But can you display the image in the browser by typing its path in the location bar? Also, see if there are errors in the browser console. And the server might use case sensitive path names while your local OS does not; check that too.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lester you were right. The problem was the letter case. Once I matched the letter casing the site works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!